# Fade a div after showing for couple of seconds

Tags: jquery, html, timeout, fade

**Situation:**

I create small information divs in the corner of the page. Those are generated by messages I set. The information are placed above each other. The divs have a `class = "informatiemelding"`.

**To accomplish:**

Is there a way to add a fade timer for each div that has the class name "informatiemelding", so that no matter how many information divs are on screen they will all disappear a number of seconds. I have jQuery. I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(".informatiemelding").setTimeout(function () {
   $(this).fadeOut('slow');
});
</script>
```

But that just gave me a error that "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setTimeout'". So I'm grabbing the divs in the wrong way I suppose.

Since I'm a utter noob with jQuery can somebody explain me what to do? Javascript isn't something that I understand. Getting better at it but I'm more in to PHP :P

Comment: Now i know what I'm doing wrong. The script has to be placed after the div's. Might be obvious, but I had no idea that <script> are allowed to be in the body. I thought that they always had to be in the <head>. The $ still doesn't work but replaced with jQuery it does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
jQuery("div.informatiemelding").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
```

Comment: when i use: <script type="text/javascript">
$("div.informatiemelding").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
</script> I get a error message: Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function. any idea why?

Comment: I'll update the above code to something that should work for you. Usually, `$(whatever)` is the same thing as `jQuery(whatever)`, but it sounds like jQuery isn't registering the $ as a shortcut for you or something... If it still isn't working, that means jQuery isn't loaded or is loading after your code.

Comment: Now i know what I'm doing wrong. The script has to be placed after the div's. Might be obvious, but I had no idea that <script> are allowed to be in the body. I thought that they always had to be in the <head>. The $ still doesn't work but replaced with jQuery it does.

Comment: There might be another javascript library you have loaded that is overriding the $ shortcut. Not sure. Honestly, while the $ is always convenient, a maximum-compatibility best-practice is to use jQuery instead anyways.

Answer (score 4):

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(".informatiemelding").fadeOut('slow');
}, 1000 /* Time to wait in milliseconds */);
```

Comment: U've asked good qns. I upvoted u back to your old points. People like these make SO an awful place!